# How can I create an Open Directory network user with a command?

Tags: macos, open-directory

I know I can create a local user with:

```
sudo dscl . create /Users/firstlast RealName "FIRST LAST"
```

How can I create a network user on Sierra or High Sierra?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Can we assume you are running 10.14.2 mojave and the latest server.app v 5.7.1? Please edit the body of the question if you can help with details.

Comment: Good point, updated.

Comment: OK - it's been a very long time since I usually use LDIF/LDAP loads and AD scripting - what about https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142655/how-can-i-import-os-x-mavericks-server-accounts-from-a-csv-file ? - the `dsimport` command is still present and has a manual page on Mojave.