# Create Local Network Directory User on OS X server via Terminal

Tags: terminal, network, script, user-account, open-directory

I found this post:

- [How can I create an Open Directory network user with a command?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/350566/how-can-i-create-an-open-directory-network-user-with-a-command)

but it didn't have any answers on it. I know there's a way to create a local network directory user, but I cannot find a command to do this anywhere. I'd like to create a script that makes a user given a first and last name.

I also found this post:

- [Manage Users On macOS Server 5.2 On Sierra](https://krypted.com/mac-os-x/manage-users-macos-server-5-2-sierra/)

It says there's a way to do it through terminal but I couldn't find any other articles explaining how. Unless they're talking about a local directory user and not a local *network* directory user.